How do I control the space between the bars in my BarPlot of my MUI Bar Chart?
I am very new to React and MUI I am trying to control the amount of spacing between the bars in my chart, here is the code that I have:
        <ResponsiveChartContainer
            height={300}
            dataset={dataset}
            series={[
              {
                dataKey: 'totalCost',
                type: 'bar',
                highlightScope: {
                  faded: 'global',
                  highlighted: 'item',
                },
              },
            ]}
            xAxis={[{ scaleType: 'band', dataKey: 'monthAbbreviated', id: 'x-axis-id' }]}
            colors={['rgba(101,41,158,0.2)']}
            sx={{
              ['& .MuiBarElement-root']: {
                outline: '1px solid black',
                border: {
                  width: '1px',
                  color: '#2A2B30',
                  borderRadius: '4px',
                },
              },
            }}
          >
            <BarPlot
              onItemClick={(_event, d) => setState(dataset[d.dataIndex]!.rangeKey)}
              tooltip={{ trigger: 'item' }}
              slotProps={{
                bar: {
                  rx: 4,
                  ry: 4,
                },
              }}
            />
            <ChartsTooltip trigger='item' slots={{ itemContent: CustomItemTooltip }} />
            <ChartsXAxis position='bottom' axisId='x-axis-id' tickSize={0} />
            <ChartsGrid horizontal />
          </ResponsiveChartContainer>

What I want to do is set the space between the bars to be explicitly 11 pixels, I know there must be a way to do this can anyone enlighten me here?
Thank you!
